# RestKit duplicates in cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I get some strange duplicates in my cahce

my data model is

[image: data model]

I'm getting this json input:

```
{
    "pages": 1,
    "salads": [
        {
            "id": 374,
            "img": "http://salatiki.com.ua/images/mini/20120114_457.jpg",
            "ingredCount": 5,
            "ingredients": "курятина, яблоко, сыр твёрдый, икра красная, майонез",
            "my_favorite": 1,
            "name": "Сердце",
            "rating": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 336,
            "img": "http://salatiki.com.ua/images/mini/20111229_2110.jpg",
            "ingredCount": 6,
            "ingredients": "креветки, салат, помидор, чеснок, майонез, сметана",
            "my_favorite": 1,
            "name": "Итальянский с креветками",
            "rating": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

array "salads" can have more on less objects that in example

here is my log:

```
    Fetch result: (
        "<SSaladCards: 0x797437b0> (entity: SSaladCards; id: 0x79635760 <x-coredata://9277267C-0FAA-4E7B-BCE2-157DA4CF9D34/SSaladCards/p13> ; data: {\n    sPages = 1;\n    salads =     (\n        \"0x796529e0 <x-coredata://9277267C-0FAA-4E7B-BCE2-157DA4CF9D34/SSaladsCardData/p2>\",\n        \"0x79d613f0 <x-coredata://9277267C-0FAA-4E7B-BCE2-157DA4CF9D34/SSaladsCardData/p1>\"\n    );\n})",
        "<SSaladCards: 0x79d438a0> (entity: SSaladCards; id: 0x79d59900 <x-coredata://9277267C-0FAA-4E7B-BCE2-157DA4CF9D34/SSaladCards/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
        "<SSaladCards: 0x79d67830> (entity: SSaladCards; id: 0x79d439a0 <x-coredata://9277267C-0FAA-4E7B-BCE2-157DA4CF9D34/SSaladCards/p3> ; data: <fault>)",
        "<SSaladCards: 0x79d43930> (entity: SSaladCards; id: 0x79d439b0 <x-coredata://9277267C-0FAA-4E7B-BCE2-157DA4CF9D34/SSaladCards/p4> ; data: <fault>)",
....
```

my code:
my store and manager was allocated in appDelegate, these code i use in first ViewController, so i call sharedManager and defaultStore

```
RKEntityMapping *saladPageMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([SSaladCards class]) inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
            [saladPageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"pages" : @"sPages", }];
            saladPageMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"sPages"];

            RKEntityMapping *saladsBodyMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([SSaladsCardData class]) inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
            [saladsBodyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"id" : @"sId",
                                                                      @"img" : @"sImage",
                                                                      @"name" : @"sName",
                                                                      @"rating" : @"sRating",
                                                                      @"ingredients" : @"sIngredients",
                                                                      @"ingredCount" : @"sIngredientsCount",
                                                                      @"my_favorite" : @"sFavorites" }];
            saladsBodyMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"sId"];

            [saladPageMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"salads"
                                                                                             toKeyPath:@"salads"
                                                                                           withMapping:saladsBodyMapping]];

            RKResponseDescriptor *saladPageDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:saladPageMapping
                                                                                                     method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                                pathPattern:nil
                                                                                                    keyPath:nil
                                                                                                statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

            [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptorsFromArray: @[saladPageDescriptor]];

            NSURLRequest *salRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://salatiki.com.ua/api/get.php?getByCat=-1&page=1&ukey=%@", [keychainWrapper objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]]]];
            RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *saladOperation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:salRequest responseDescriptors:@[saladPageDescriptor]];
            saladOperation.managedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
            saladOperation.managedObjectCache = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].managedObjectCache;
            NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
            [operationQueue addOperation:saladOperation];
```

how i fetch objects

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)saladCardFetcehdResController {
    if (_saladCardFetcehdResController != nil) {
        return _saladCardFetcehdResController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([SSaladCards class])];

    NSSortDescriptor *pages = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sPages" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[pages]];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    self.saladCardFetcehdResController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Salad"];
    self.saladCardFetcehdResController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.saladCardFetcehdResController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Salad Fetch count: %i",[[self.saladCardFetcehdResController fetchedObjects] count]);
        NSLog(@"Salad Fetch result: %@",[self.saladCardFetcehdResController fetchedObjects]);
    }

    return _saladCardFetcehdResController;
}
```

each time i make a request to server it add to my cache one "fault" object

```
"<SSaladCards: 0x79d438a0> (entity: SSaladCards; id: 0x79d59900 <x-coredata://9277267C-0FAA-4E7B-BCE2-157DA4CF9D34/SSaladCards/p1> ; data: <fault>)"
```

why do i have duplicates? Help please :(

Answer (score 0):

Using a cache on your FRC isn't likely to help, though it probably isn't the cause of this issue.

I guess that you haven't configured a fetch request or in-memory `managedObjectCache` (to be used by `RKManagedObjectStore`) as this is the mechanism which allows RestKit to find existing items in the data store and update them instead of create new instances.

Comment: Thank you, how can i configure fetch request?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `managedObjectCache` on `RKManagedObjectStore`?

Comment: yes, my managedObjectCache is not nil, i don't understand why i have duplicates, because the same code in my app works fine

Comment: i mean that similar code in my project works fine, i'll create a sample project in some of these days and write to you, maybe if you show all code you can help me. Thank you.